# JS| Initialised object is undefined after function accessing it is run more than once

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, javascript-scope

I am trying to reduce the global variables in my Chrome extension to reduce the 'spaghettiness' or ambiguity in my JavaScript.

I am trying to attempt this by having an init function that declares these otherwise global variables within a mousedown eventListener callback function that is likely to be fired more than once.

This is so that I can pass these variables + events through to other eventListener callbacks (namely a mouseup callback) as arguments of such callbacks.

I have decomposed the issue into a separate file:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
isVarsInitOnce = false;

function executesMoreThanOnce() {
    const initVariables = function() {
        console.log('runs once');

        const bools = {
            boolOne: false,
            boolTwo: false,
            boolThree: false
        };

        const events = {
            clickEvent:
                function(event) {
                    //do stuff
                },
            keyEvent:
                function(event) {
                    //do other stuff
                }
        };

        return {
            bools: bools,
            events: events
        }
    };

    if (!isVarsInitOnce) {
        isVarsInitOnce = true;
        let vars = initVariables();

        var booleanObject = vars.bools;
        var eventObject = vars.events;
    }

    console.log('objects: ', booleanObject, eventObject);

    //attempting to access initialised variable after function is executed more than once will cause an error.
    //this is because the booleanObject is now undefined.
    booleanObject.boolOne = true;
}

//runs twice
for (let i=0; i<2; i++) {
    executesMoreThanOnce();
}
```

The method I have used to control the execution of the `initVariables()` is a global boolean variable, `isVarsInitOnce` which is effective at intialising the variables and setting the object for use in the `executesMoreThanOnce()` function once.

The objects are able to be accessed in the first instance that the function is called in the `for` loop, however the objects are `undefined` when they are attempted to be accessed in the secondary instance that the function is called in the `for` loop.

This is signified in rather clearly in the console output:

```
runs once
test.js:38 objects:  {boolOne: false, boolTwo: false, boolThree: false} {clickEvent: ƒ, keyEvent: ƒ}
test.js:38 objects:  undefined undefined //<--- (function called 2nd time)
test.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'boolOne' of undefined
    at executesMoreThanOnce (test.js:42)
    at test.js:47
```

I am unsure why this is occurring.

Can anyone help me to understand why this does not work properly?

Does anyone have a better suggestion for reducing global variables with regards to my case?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a look at some reading on scope and closure in JS and I think I have found a solution to the decomposed problem in my original question.

The answer given by Aber Abou-Rahma does not solve my issue because the variables are reset per function call of `executesMoreThanOnce()`.

This is not what I was looking for because I only wanted the variables to be initially set in the first instance that the function is called (because in my actual project the `executesMoreThanOnce()` function essentially represents a click event callback that requires the data to persist when the event is re-triggered).

My solution uses an Immediately-invoked Function Expression (IIFE). to initialise the variables locally within the scope of the IIFE, and release the variables into the global scope in its returned `get` method:

**test.js**

```
const TEST = (function() {
    let booleans = {
        boolOne: false,
        boolTwo: false,
        boolThree: false
    };

    let events = {
        clickEvent:
            function(event) {
                //do stuff
            },
        keyEvent:
            function(event) {
                //do other stuff
            }
    };

    return {
        executesMoreThanOnce: function(booleans, events, index) {
            booleanObject = booleans;
            eventsObject = events;

            if (i == 2) {
                booleanObject.boolTwo = true;
            }
            else if (i == 4) {
                booleanObject.boolOne = true;
                booleanObject.boolTwo = false;
            }

            console.log('booleanObject: ', booleanObject);
        },
        get variables() {
            return {
                booleans,
                events
            }
        }
    };
}());

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    TEST.executesMoreThanOnce(TEST.variables.booleans, TEST.variables.events, i);
}
```

You can now see in the console that the `TEST.executesMoreThanOnce()` function starts using the initial variables defined locally within the `TEST` IIFE function:

```
i = 0 | booleanObject:  {boolOne: false, boolTwo: false, boolThree: false}
i = 1 | booleanObject:  {boolOne: false, boolTwo: false, boolThree: false}
i = 2 | booleanObject:  {boolOne: false, boolTwo: true, boolThree: false}
i = 3 | booleanObject:  {boolOne: false, boolTwo: true, boolThree: false}
i = 4 | booleanObject:  {boolOne: true, boolTwo: false, boolThree: false}
```

We can also now see that once the i value meets certain conditions in the `TEST.executesMoreThanOnce()` function, the booleans begin to switch, but more importantly, these changes persist between function calls.

I'm still not sure I understand the abstraction beneath the IIFE fully. but I can clearly see in the code which variables belong to the scope of which functions they are used in (improving readability). This was my goal in the first place.

If anybody would like to correct me on something I have misunderstood you are more than welcome to before I begin trying to implement this into my project.

Answer (score 1):

First Both  booleanObject and  eventObject  needed to be declared outside the if statement to be in scope.
Second if you need to run executesMoreThanOnce more than once you need to set isVarsInitOnce to false in the for loop

```
           let  isVarsInitOnce = false;
           
function executesMoreThanOnce() {
    const initVariables = function() {
        console.log('runs once');

        const bools = {
            boolOne: false,
            boolTwo: false,
            boolThree: false
        };

        const events = {
            clickEvent:
                function(event) {
                    //do stuff
                },
            keyEvent:
                function(event) {
                    //do other stuff
                }
        };

        return {
            bools: bools,
            events: events
        }
    };
      let booleanObject ; // declaring booleanObject outside the if statement
        let eventObject ; // declaring eventObject outside the if statement
    if (!isVarsInitOnce) {
        isVarsInitOnce = true;
        let vars = initVariables();

        booleanObject = vars.bools;
        eventObject = vars.events;
    }

    console.log('objects: ', booleanObject, eventObject);

    //attempting to access initialised variable after function is executed more than once will cause an error.
    //this is because the booleanObject is now undefined.
    booleanObject.boolOne = true;
}

//runs 5 times
for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {// Will execute 5 times
    executesMoreThanOnce();
    isVarsInitOnce = false;
}
```

***Edit***

Sorry my bad I did not fully understand your requirements. Check out the following:

***JavaScript***

```
    // This will be the object that holds your variables
     let vars;
       
       function executesMoreThanOnce(obj) {
           const initVariables = function(obj) {
              
               console.log('runs once and obj = ' + obj);
               if (obj == undefined) {
                
                console.log('initialize once');
                    const bools = {
                        boolOne: false,
                        boolTwo: false,
                        boolThree: false
                    };
            
                    const events = {
                        clickEvent:
                            function(event) {
                                //do stuff
                            },
                        keyEvent:
                            function(event) {
                                //do other stuff
                            }
                    };
                   
                   return (function(){
                        return {bools: bools,
                                events: events};
                    })();
                }
                // If vars object, "which we passed as argument", is initialized once before just return it
                return vars;
               
           };

           vars = initVariables(vars);
               
           let    booleanObject = vars.bools;
           let    eventObject = vars.events;
               
           
       
           console.log('objects: ', booleanObject, eventObject);
       
           //attempting to access initialised variable after function is executed more than once will cause an error.
           //this is because the booleanObject is now undefined.
           // Yes you can now access the variables
           booleanObject.boolOne = true;
       }
       
       //runs 5 times
       for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {// Will execute 5 times
            // Removed the bool flag and now passing the vars object as argument
           executesMoreThanOnce(vars);
          
           //executesMoreThanOnce();
           //isVarsInitOnce = false;
       }
```

[Check it out on Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/brc9fvms/)

Comment: Then the variables are reset every time the executesMoreThanOnce function is called. I only want to initialise these variables once in the first instance that the function is called